# How to Insert headers and footers using Office-js in Excel Worksheet

Tags: office-js

We want to insert text into headers and footers of an Excel Worksheet using the Office-js Api. Is there any way available now or in the near future to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This feature got introduced in ExcelApi 1.9 (this May). [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.headerfooter)

Some example code:

```js
Excel.run(async (context)=>{
  const sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
  sheets.load({$all: true}); // Load all sheets

  const headerFooter = sheets.getActiveWorksheet().pageLayout.headersFooters.defaultForAllPages;
  headerFooter.load({$all: true}); // Load header/footer

  await context.sync();

  headerFooter.set({leftHeader: 'something'});
});
```

Comment: There is no need for a load or a context sync if your just setting on active sheet, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While [@RoelVB code did help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57507949/5079799), I also found it quite confusing. For one, there is no need to load so many options.

In fact, I only load properties if I'm looping over each worksheet. If I'm setting on a specific worksheet, no need. And, when I do load, I load a non-existent property. I'm not 100% why the load is needed, but see this post for looping over worksheets --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/50285934/5079799

Anyway, here the function I built which you can pass a Header_Footer_Obj to and optional specify worksheets/worksheet or nothing (activesheet).

```
async function Set_Header_Footer(context, Header_Footer_Obj, Opt_All_WSs, Opt_WS) {
    if (Opt_All_WSs == true) {
        var sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
        sheets.load("$none");
        await context.sync();
        sheets.items.forEach(sheet => sheet.pageLayout.headersFooters.defaultForAllPages.set(Header_Footer_Obj, false));
        return context;
    }
    if (Opt_WS != undefined) {
        return Opt_WS.pageLayout.headersFooters.defaultForAllPages.set(Header_Footer_Obj, false);    
    }
    if (Opt_WS == undefined && Opt_All_WSs != true) {
        return context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().pageLayout.headersFooters.defaultForAllPages.set(Header_Footer_Obj, false);    
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
var Header_Footer_Obj = {
    leftHeader: 'leftHeader',
    centerHeader: 'centerHeader',
    rightHeader: 'rightHeader',
    leftFooter: 'leftFooter',
    centerFooter: 'centerFooter',
    rightFooter: 'rightFooter',
}
await Set_Header_Footer(context, Header_Footer_Obj, true)

var Header_Footer_Obj = {
    leftHeader: '2leftHeader',
    centerHeader: '2centerHeader',
    rightHeader: null,
    leftFooter: '2leftFooter',
    centerFooter: null,
    rightFooter: '2rightFooter',
}

var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet2")
await Set_Header_Footer(context, Header_Footer_Obj, false, ws)

var Header_Footer_Obj = {
    leftHeader: 'getActiveWorksheet',
    centerHeader: 'getActiveWorksheet',
    rightHeader: null,
    leftFooter: 'getActiveWorksheet',
    centerFooter: null,
    rightFooter: 'getActiveWorksheet',
}
await Set_Header_Footer(context, Header_Footer_Obj, false)
```